# Trouble writing program data to txt file in a Maven program

Tags: java, maven

I'm tutoring someone and wrote a small program (4 packages, 6 classes) using Java/Maven.
In short, its Swing UI allows you to clock a timestamp (using a button), and when you have clocked two timestamps, it adds the completed shift to a table. There's also a Pay button that tells how much is due based on the rate and after additional user confirmation clears the table of timestamps.

I am trying to store my timestamps in a txt file because they're easy to work with. Everything works fine as a raw Java program, but when I converted to Maven I immediately ran into the issue that the file structure of the program works differently either after compiling/when it is running. Either way, the issue is the same, and I had to modify my file IO.

Currently, my data file is in `src/main/resources/logs.txt`. After some Maven research, I have passed in `/logs.txt` for my file output path. I try and access my file with a FileWriter as follows:

```
FileWriter writer;
try {
    writer = new FileWriter('/' + path, true);  // Set to true so that we don't overwrite the file
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
}
```

However, when I run my code and try and close it (where this method is used), I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: \logs.txt (Access is denied)
```

It's safe to assume this is being thrown as an IOException, but I use IAE for consistent catching with one clause. (I am aware that is bad practice for error handling.)

This error indicates that my FileWriter can locate my file but not open it. That being said, running the program via the command line as su/admin works fine, but this decreases the usability of my program which is bad as I want to distribute this to the person I am tutoring. I would rather not make my program difficult to use.

I'm assuming this error has something to do with how I am accessing the file, but all of the fixes are for plain Java programs. What can I change to make the program run as a normal user? After an hour or such of searching I haven't been able to find a successful. I'm willing to try anything either proposed or linked. Thanks.

EDIT: In case it makes writing an answer easier as I know class stuff is more necessary with Maven, my main class is just titled GUI, and is set as manifest fine.

EDIT 2: Below is a list of anything new I've tried since making this post.

- I tried setting the file at the path as writable using the File java.io object, but got the same result.

Comment: You can't write to a file that's being used as a resource. Use an actual file in [${user.home}](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/16-javasystemproperties)

Comment: @g00se Hey, thanks so much. I didn't know jar files were read only but that makes sense based on program structures I've seen before using jar. I appreciate it.